# How to automate git-bash commands on windows machine?

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, jenkins, git-bash

How to automate these commands in windows. Answer could be obvious **".bat"** file.

**sample.bat**

```
C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe
cd c:\directory\
eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add "id_rsa"
git clone repo
```

By doing this, a new bash window opens but i don't see these commands executing there.

And also, how do i do this via jenkins as well (On windows slave) ?

**Answer (As suggested by poke):**
Passing multiple arguments as well.

```
git-bash.exe -c "cd /c/dictionary; eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add 'id_rsa'; git clone repo"
```

Comment: @Andras Deak : Have you gone through the question correctly ? Have you tried the above commands ? Did you try the same process on jenkins as well ? Marking as duplicate is very easy without any solution. Could you please help me here.

Comment: *I* did mark it as a duplicate, not Andras. And if you go through the linked question, you should get enough ideas on how to run an arbitrary list of commands automatically using Git bash.

Comment: @Andras Deak : I apologize. Poke : I tried possible batch file ways, but didn't workout. Looks like I'm missing something. How to execute bash mode on windows slave machine from jenkins ? How to write batch file for above scenario ? Could you help me here ?

Comment: As explained in the linked question, you use the `-c` argument to pass commands to `git-bash.exe`, or even run a bash file that way.

Comment: @Poke : how do i pass these 3 different commands ? 1)cd c:\directory\
 2)eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add "id_rsa" 3)git clone repo

Comment: `git-bash.exe -c "cd /c/dictionary; eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add 'id_rsa'; git clone repo"`